# Trying to dynamically generate a HTML drop down list in a JSP from my postgres DB

Tags: html, postgresql, jsp, drop-down-menu

I am trying to dynamically generate a drop down list that contains the second column of my table "city" from my database and I am using postgresql as my DBMS. The drop down list generates on my JSP page and the correct number of options are generated. My problem is that all of the options in the drop down list are just blank white space. I'm pretty sure I am properly connected to the database, I am just not too sure why the contents of my drop down list are empty.

```
<html>
<body>

<%  
    try{
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/db");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM city");
%>
<div id = "menu">
    <select>
        <%
            while (rs.next()){
        %>
        <option>
            <% rs.getString(2); %>
        </option>
        <% } %>
    </select>
</div>
<%
    }

    catch (Exception e){
    out.println("ERROR: " + e);
    }
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is data present in database for column '2' ? Post that data here and also the table column detais

Comment: Yeah there is data in column '2'. Column '2' consists of city names in the form of a char array. There's 5 rows in column 2 right now and when I run my jsp 5 blank selections show up in the drop down list.

Comment: @KylePhoneDial i think you have missed Expression use : <%= rs.getString(2); %> .

Answer (score 0):

To print the value to the html page, you need to use the JSP expression as `<%= expression %>`.

This is not correct in your code and is causing the issue.
So, change your JSP expression inside `<option>` as shown below:

```
<option>
    <%= rs.getString(2); %>
</option>
```